# Enableing the url field in picture uploads

Tags: php, wordpress, url

In WordPress, if you upload a Picture in your Media-Library there is a URL field that is grey. I need an option to make it accessable. I want to embed a always changing picture from a third party website in the Team area to keep the pictures up to date without uploading them by myself every day.

Is there a solution, such as a easy way to search for the URL with phpmyadmin or something and change it there?

Comment: Can't you simply link to the 3rd party website?

Comment: That wouldnt realy fit my needs. I need to embed the picture into the wordpress team carousel. I dont know a other way to do it. I cant upload a picture and change it's url after that so i basicly need a work around.